# dropdown menu , remove class if its open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create dropdown menu, I'm doing it in this way, by default on dropdown menu I'm doing

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

then im creating event on click and based on that context im toggling class

```
.active { display block; }
```

now I cant figure out how can I remove that `.active` class when I click on other button or in document, I don't want to keep dropdown active class if user click on other button [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLkpxkb/6/)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after comment**

You don't need to put `""` with `this` keyword. Your code line should be:

```
$(this).siblings("ul.dropdown").toggleClass("active");
```

**Complete Code**

```
$(function () {
var dropdown = $(".btn").find("a");
dropdown.on("click", function() {
$("ul.dropdown.active").removeClass("active");  //added new line
$(this).siblings("ul.dropdown").toggleClass("active");
});
}());
```

**[Updated Code with Remove Class](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLkpxkb/9/)**

Comment: thanks, but there is just one problem if dropdown one is open and i click on btn two , i want to close dropdown one, for example if dropdown one has class .active and i click on dropdown btn two, i want to remove class active from dropdown btn one.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pnLkpxkb/8/

```
$(function () {
    // The user clicks anywhere in the document
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        // If a dropdown has a class active AND if the dropdown or the link is not the target of the click
        if ($("ul.dropdown").hasClass("active") && !$("ul.dropdown, .btn > a").is(e.target)) {
            // Remove class active
            $("ul.dropdown.active").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
    var dropdown = $(".btn > a");
    // The user clicks on a toggle link (One or Two)
    dropdown.on("click", function () {
        // Remove the active class from the active element
        $("ul.dropdown.active").removeClass("active");
        // Add class to the relevant sub menu
        $(this).siblings("ul.dropdown").addClass("active");
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) don't work as you want. For your case i suggest to go this way:

```
$(function () {
    var dropdown = $(".btn").find("a");
    dropdown.on("click", function() {
        $("ul.dropdown").removeClass("active");//add this to remove class from all ul .dropdowns
        $(this).siblings("ul.dropdown").addClass("active");//Add class to your ul dropdown. Here you can use toggleClass too
    });

}());
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLkpxkb/12/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $("ul.dropdown").removeClass('active');
    });

    $(".btn a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("ul.dropdown").removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings("ul.dropdown").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLkpxkb/13/).